# List of "regular" english words

Tags: nlp, word-list

So I found these 3 resources:

- [479k english words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words)
- [100k most popular english words from Wiktionary](https://gist.github.com/h3xx/1976236)
- [Google's most frequent 10,000 words](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english)

I don't mind that in the list of 479k words there are words like `b` and `u` (words of which I've never seen), because this includes super obscure stuff. But what I'm surprised to find is that the Wiktionary frequent list includes these words:

```
b
be
bel
bl
bleu
bu
eu
l
lb
le
leu
lu
lub
```

In addition, the wiki list *doesn't* include these words!

```
lube
neg
tab
```

That is, there are many words that the wiki list has that I wouldn't think of as "regular words", and there are many "regular words" that the wiki list doesn't have.

So my question is if there is a list of "regular" words for download on the web in the public domain. By regular, I just mean words that you learn through reading books and such, not these words like `leu` and `bl` which for some reason are in the wiki featured list.

This is for an autocomplete component.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already know there is no operational definition for "regular". This is because you need to define it yourself based on the needs of your project. Are emojis words? If you're analyzing twitter data then it's probably beneficial to include them.

A couple jumping off points to help you define "regular" for your project are:

- a frequency metric (does this word appear at least XX% of the time in your corpus)
- an agreement between sources (words that appear in all three of your word lists)
- human judgement (do this yourself, or use mturk and ask "is this a word, yes or no?")